# symfony2 cache on web hosting

Tags: apache, symfony

Just deployed project on the external web hosting server, unfortunately provider dosent ofer ssh connection for the console. I manage to set cache and log permitions to 777 by using recursive properties with WinSCP. Does anyone know how to permamently set correct permitions so when symfony creates new subfolder right premition will be granted?

Comment: You have to talk with your hosting provider to ensure that the user the web server (`Apache`?) is running as has permission to write in the `cache` and `log` directories.

Comment: Thanks Oscar, is there any way to set this up in .htaccess file?

Comment: No, as far as I know, .htaccess does not change file permissions...

Comment: Thanks for advice.